# Oracle ADF 10g to 11g migration

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-adf

I have an ADF project in 10g, and i want to migrate it to 11g 
i am getting the following errors:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected element 'web-resource-collection@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'auth-constraint@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element security-constraint@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
  problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4c: Expected element 'web-resource-collection@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' before the end of the content in element security-constraint@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1604)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadDescriptor(WebAppModule.java:1358)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:372)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected element 'web-resource-collection@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'auth-constraint@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element security-constraint@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
  problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4c: Expected element 'web-resource-collection@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' before the end of the content in element security-constraint@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:245)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:231)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:155)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:323)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have got rid of the error after i removed the security roles from the ViewController and Model, in the web.xml files.